# Remove TFS Project without use resources

Tags: tfs

At my company we have an existing TFS with hundreds of projects, and this has led us to need a very powerful server in order to handle TFS.

I would like to know how to optimise the use of resources, starting from space.

As far as I've read, using "TFSDeleteProject" it would delete all traces of the project without leave trace (as long as there are not work item shared with this project and another).

Is this correct? I've read conflicting information about this:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/tfs/server/ref/command-line/tfsdeleteproject-cmd
Indicates that there wont be traces left.

However
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms181482(VS.80).aspx
States: "When you run TFSDeleteProject, the system places the source control data in a deleted state in the operational store. It does not actually remove the data from the database, nor does it reclaim the disk space. Also, the system does not remove the warehouse data originating from the team project."

Thanks,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first link covers TFS 2018, TFS 2017, TFS 2015 and TFS 2013.

The second link covers TFS 2008.

Which version of TFS are you using?

Comment: Thanks, that was it.

Answer (score 1):

Nera's answer is right, the coverage is different.

Besides please also note that some [Data That May Remain Undeleted](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/tfs/server/ref/command-line/tfsdeleteproject-cmd#data-that-may-remain-undeleted) even for the new versions of TFS (the first link)：

> The following data might remain in the deployment after
>   TFSDeleteProject successfully completes:
>
> - **Project data in the cube.** Project data remains in the cube until the    cube is rebuilt, at which time the warehouse controller
>     service    removes all of the historic build data that has been
>     deleted from the    Team Foundation databases.
> - **Build drop files and folders.** Build binaries, build log files, and    log files containing test results are published during the
>     build    process. The locations for these files are not deleted. If
>     you want    to remove these files, you must remove them manually.
> - **Work item tracking metadata that is shared.** TFSDeleteProject does not    delete any metadata for work item tracking that is shared
>     between    projects.
> - **Version control shelvesets containing shared code.** Version control    shelvesets are not deleted if there is code in the
>     shelveset from    multiple projects.

Comment: Thank you for you answer Andy. I was aware of the data that could remain, specially regarding shared projects. But I got confused with the second link, now all makes sense.